# How can I view an uploaded docx file in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, docx, download-manager

I am working on a download management system in asp.net and I can upload and download a docx file. I want to view the uploaded file. I tried using google API but looks like I have to upload the file in google drive itself in order to be able to view it from google drive. I don't want to upload the file in google drive. Is there any other API that helps me to just view the uploaded docx file?

It would be even better if it can be viewed as well!

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it." Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

Use an iframe to embed `File.embedLink`, documented on

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files#resource

Answer (score 0):

I assume you know how to upload files in ASP.net

Using Office Web Apps you can achieve that, provide like of your uploaded document on your site, when the user clicks it will open in the browser it self [Link](http://blogs.office.com/b/officewebapps/archive/2013/04/10/office-web-viewer-view-office-documents-in-a-browser.aspx), Read the documentation

[Here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/web-apps/view-office-documents-online-FX102727753.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA102724036) is the link for API Site